# spark Scala Read Avro and save it

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I used the below code to read the avro file in spark scala.

```
 val buf = scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer.empty[GenericRecord]
 while(dataFileReader.hasNext)  {
     buf += dataFileReader.next
  }
```

I want to save the output of this in text file . Please help me out

Answer (score 0):

You can use the avro-tools utilities to do so

avro-tools fromtext from_fille.avro to_file.txt